# How to group similar rows in R

Tags: r, grouping

I have a table as follows:

```
   Rptname     Score

    Bebo23        8
    Bebo22        9
    Bebo19        10
    Alt88         12
    Alt67         11
    Jimm          5
    Jimm2         7
```

etc.
I would like to sum into groups those rows that are similar. ie

```
     Bebo         27
     Alt          22
     Jimm         12
```

The beginning of the row name is always the similar part to group on but the number of characters that are similar can vary. I appreciate that I will have to define the groups and probably using some kind of regular expression but I'm not sure how to group and sum on this basis. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can strip off the numbers at the end using `sub` and do `aggregate`

```
do.call(`data.frame`, aggregate(Score~cbind(Rptname=sub('\\d+$', '', 
                        Rptname)), df, sum))
#    Rptname Score
#1     Alt    23
#2    Bebo    27
#3    Jimm    12
```

Or use `transform` with `aggregate` (as suggested by @docendo discimus)

```
aggregate(Score ~ Rptname, transform(df, Rptname = sub("\\d+$", 
                        "", Rptname)), sum)
```

Or an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, .(Score=sum(Score)),
           by=list(Rptname=sub('\\d+$','', Rptname))]
```

Or using `rowsum`  (suggested by @alexis_laz

```
with(df, rowsum(Score, sub('\\d+$', '', Rptname)))
#     [,1]
#Alt    23
#Bebo   27
#Jimm   12
```

#### Update

If the grouping is based on first three characters, you can use `substr`

```
aggregate(Score~Rptname, transform(df, Rptname=substr(Rptname, 1,3)), sum)
#   Rptname Score
#1     Alt    23
#2     Beb    27
#3     Jim    12
```

Comment: Or similarly `aggregate(Score ~ Rptname, transform(DF, Rptname = sub("\\d+$", "", Rptname)), sum)`

Comment: Since the operation is summing, another useful function is `rowsum`; `rowsum(DF$Score, gsub("\\d+$", "", DF$Rptname))`

Comment: @akrun Long time. I haven't found enough time to carefully check SO this month so far. I'm catching up today. I am not familiar with this `.` in data.table yet. How do you read this?

Comment: @jazzurro Glad that you came back.  You can use either `list(` or just `.(`.

Comment: @akrun Thank you very much. I want to clarify your first suggestion as well. Do you need `do.call` ? It seems that the `aggregate` part is already returning a data frame.

Comment: Ok great. If I want to group in just the first three letters how would I do this ( rather than relying on stripping numbers)

Comment: @user3632206, You can use `substr`, ie. `aggregate(Score~Rptname, transform(DF, Rptname=substr(Rptname, 1,3)), sum)`

Answer (score 4):

With dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(Rptname = sub("\\d+$", "", Rptname)) %>% summarise(Score = sum(Score))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#  Rptname Score
#1     Alt    23
#2    Bebo    27
#3    Jimm    12
```

Update:

If you want to group by the first three letters in "Rptname", you can use the following code in dplyr:

```
DF %>% group_by(Rptname = substr(Rptname, 1, 3)) %>% summarise(Score = sum(Score))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#  Rptname Score
#1     Alt    23
#2     Beb    27
#3     Jim    12
```